# exclude junit lib from building apk in android studio

Tags: android, junit

I have Android studio projected imported from eclipse. I have started unit testing for this project. here are the dependency added,

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // Unit testing dependencies
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use Mockito
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    // some more ..
}
```

when I am building .apk file, this .apk contains junit library.
How do i exclude this junit library from .apk?
I have searched for these question from last few days but could find solution.
Please help me on this.

Comment: post your gradle here.

Comment: this dependancy i have added in my gradle  file                       'dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // Unit testing dependencies
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use Mockito
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19' }'

Comment: @Suhas : is this enough portion from gradle you you need whole gradle file its very large file?

Comment: have you checked any other library project contains junit dependency? cross check once.

Comment: please some one help me!

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // Unit testing dependencies
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' // if you don't need remove this line and sync again...
    // Set this dependency if you want to use Mockito
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    // some more ..
}

Answer (score 0):

Use `testCompile` instead of `compile` for unit-test dependencies; `androidTestCompile` for instrumentation test dependencies.

Comment: @Suhas: how do i check other library project contains junit dependency

Comment: @ Egor :I have tried that before. i have added testCompile then it won't detect junit library.

Comment: i.e. only in src/test/java directory?

Comment: Yes , see if i use testCompile, I will get Error:(13, 17) error: package org.junit does not exist

Comment: Well, this is how it should be configured. Just make sure once again that you're using latest stable versions of Android Studio, Gradle plugin, build tools, etc., and perform a "./gradlew clean" from the command line

Comment: i tries all these ways to do it ..but no success :-(

Comment: It happened to me a couple of times that the project failed to pick up newly added library, and restarting Android Studio helped.

Comment: just 1 min i will list down the all the tools versions here